# Kotlin use out keyword with multi generic type

Tags: generics, kotlin

I define a abstract class like this.

```
ViewCreator<V>() where V : View, V : OnUpdate
```

so how can  I use the ViewCreator interface with **out** keyword

```
fun getViewCreateor(): ViewCreator<out *???*> {
  .....
}
```

what is the right syntax to replace *???*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use:

```kotlin
fun <V> getViewCreator(): ViewCreator<out V> where V : View, V : OnUpdate {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, the `out` keyword could be moved to the `ViewCreator` declaration to slightly simplify its usage, since it is probably not also a View consumer.

Comment: @Tenfour Yes exactly!